# Cast bigint to decimal(18,5) in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to cast a bigint to decimal(18,5) in hive and I'm not getting any fraction values after converting to decimal(18,5).

Let's take the below bigint values

```
99000
999000
499000
350000
344000000
```

After casting to decimal(18,5), I'm expecting something like below

```
0.99000
9.99000
4.99000
3.50000
3440.00000
```

I'm trying the below query.

```
select col_a, cast(col_a as decimal(18,5)) from table;
```

From above query, I'm getting output same as input

```
99000
999000
499000
350000
344000000
```

Also, I tried dividing the input with 10^5 and casting to decimal(18,5).

```
select col_a, cast(col_a/100000 as decimal(18,5)) from table;
```

Above query is returning the fraction values, but not having 5 digits after the decimal.

```
0.99
9.99
4.99
3.5
344000000
```

Could someone please correct me what I'm missing or doing wrong here.

Comment: In the last dataset it should be 3440 not 344000000.

Answer (score 0):

`DECIMAL` type do not permit values larger than the range implied by the column definition.

DECIMAL(5,0) column supports a range of -99999 to 99999.

DECIMAL(M,D) column permits up to `M - D` digits to the left of the decimal point.

For example `DECIMAL(5,2)` permits -999.99 to 999.99

And the trailing zeroes are not displayed. If you need them guaranteed to be displayed, use string type and rpad() function to add zeroes at the end or something like that.

If the number cannot be cast to decimal, NULL is returned, for example the following cast returns NULL:

```
select cast(1234567890L as decimal(3,1))
```

It is not clear why do you expect `cast a bigint to decimal(18,5)` to produce some fractional numbers. cast does not divide your initial numbers.